# Oracle initialization of collection elements with not null constraint

Tags: oracle, plsql

What is the initialization value for NOT NULL element in the collection (Table/Varray)? It seems like the NULL but it is NOT NULL. Tested in **Oracle LIVE SQL (Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition - 19.2.0.0.0)**

```
declare 
    type TArrNotNull IS table of number NOT NULL;
    type TArrAllowNull IS table of number;
    arrNotNull TArrNotNull := TArrNotNull();
    arrAllowNull TArrAllowNull := TArrAllowNull();
begin
    -- NOT NULL ARRAY ELEMENTS
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('======== table/Array of number NOT NULL example ==========');    
    arrNotNull.Extend;
    IF arrNotNull(1) is null then
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NULL !!!');
    else
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NOT NULL BUT WHAT ???->['||COALESCE(arrNotNull(1),100)||']'); 
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NOT NULL BUT WHAT + 1 BECOMES NULL (LIKE REAL NULL)???->['||COALESCE(arrNotNull(1)+1,100)||']');
    end if ;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('======== table/Array of number example ==========');

    -- NOT NULL ARRAY ELEMENTS
    arrAllowNull.Extend;
    IF arrAllowNull(1) is null then
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OK IS NULL !!!');
    else
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NOT NULL !!!');
    end if ;
end;
```

RESULTS:

```
Statement processed.
======== table/Array of number NOT NUMBER example ==========
NOT NULL BUT WHAT ???->[]
NOT NULL BUT WHAT + 1 BECOMES NULL (LIKE REAL NULL)???->[100]
======== table/Array of number example ==========
OK IS NULL !!!
```

**UPD:** Also the same if you assign the value to the NUMBER variable.

```
tst:=arrNotNull(1);
if tst is null then
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('N NULL !!!');
else 
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('N NOT NULL !!!+++'); 
end if; 

if (tst+1) is null then
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('N+1 NULL !!!+++');
else 
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('N+1 NOT NULL !!!+++'); 
end if;
```

RESULT:

```
N NOT NULL !!!+++
N+1 NULL !!!+++
```

Comment: Interesting, I get `NULL !!!` for the first part in 11gR2, both locally and on a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b11b77add5c7bf8941082403861d3b2a); but the same as you [on an 18c fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b11b77add5c7bf8941082403861d3b2a). Not sure if that's an intentional change or a bug; I suspect the latter...

Comment: i have tried to dump the value and got `null`

Comment: Also, [`dump()` thinks it is null...](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=71b5e91a27a614e28f89634ae1a6455c). And for what it's worth, 12.1.0.2 shows `NULL !!!`, but 12.2.0.1 shows the same as 18c and 19c. Probably something to raise directly with Oracle?.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting. Didn't find a "value" for 18+, but in 12c you get a `NULL`.

I did shrink your code a little:

```
declare 
    type TArrNotNull IS table of varchar2(100) NOT NULL;
    arrNotNull TArrNotNull := TArrNotNull(1, 2, 3);
begin
    begin
        arrNotNull(2) := to_number(NULL); -- will throw, because null is not allowed
        dbms_output.put_line('arrNotNull(2) is null now');
    exception
        WHEN others THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('arrNotNull(2) couldn''t be set to null');
    end;

    arrNotNull.Extend;
    dbms_output.put_line('arrNotNull(4): >>>' || nvl(arrNotNull(4), 'NULL') || '<<<'); 
end;
```

Result in 12c:

```
arrNotNull(2) couldn't be set to null
arrNotNull(4): >>>NULL<<<
```

Result in 18c (same like yours):

```
arrNotNull(2) couldn't be set to null
arrNotNull(4): >>><<<
```

Also interesting is, that an Extend on a nullable `Table of` has NULL as default value:

```
declare 
    type TArrNotNull IS table of varchar2(100);
    arrNotNull TArrNotNull := TArrNotNull(1, 2, 3);
begin

    arrNotNull.Extend;
    dbms_output.put_line('arrNotNull(4): >>>' || nvl(arrNotNull(4), 'NULL') || '<<<');
end;
```

Result on all versions:

```
arrNotNull(4): >>>NULL<<<
```